# Out-File truncation of text

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have the following PowerShell script that queries a single column from a table and I want to send the results to a text file:

```
$SqlStatement = 
"SELECT Result 
FROM JobRun 
WHERE AccountID = 13 
    AND InterfaceID = 2
    AND Started BETWEEN '4/1/2016' AND '4/2/2016'"


$Result = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "xxxx" -Database "Vincent" -Query $SqlStatement -Username "rminder" -Password "xxxx"
$Result | Out-File C:\Temp\MyProject\SUP_20160401.Txt -Width 4000
```

Without the -Width parameter, the text is truncated at roughly 255 characters. Even with the -Width parameter, the text is truncated at roughly 2155 characters. It looks something like this:

```
EVV_AutoConfirmFlag|EVV_VisitRecordIndicator...
```

Is there a way I can avoid any truncation at all? I intend to run this query many times. The Result column in the SQL Server table is a varchar(max) column so it can hold very large amounts of data. In the query above, the resulting column contains ~40K bytes of text.

By the way, I also tried Export-Csv as follows, but that truncates at around 4K of text.

```
$Result | Export-Csv C:\Temp\MyProject\SUP_20160401.Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Are you tied to having a text file? If not, just send it to a csv file and you won't get truncation.

Comment: @ShawnMelton - I started out exporting to CSV. It truncates as well, at right about 4K.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are multiple issues, but it'll take a while to be sure. First off, `-MaxCharLength` might do stuff. The second is that the DataRow object's behavior is truncating the data.

Comment: If you do `$Result[-1].Result`, do you get the whole data or just a substring?

Comment: @vonPryz - Do you mean something like this: $Result[-1].Result | Export-Csv C:\Temp\HernlyProject\SUP_20160401.Csv -NoTypeInformation. If so, I get an error because InputObject is NULL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @vonPryz says there are multiple issues. This should work

```
$Result = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "xxxx" -Database "Vincent" -Query $SqlStatement -Username "rminder" -Password "xxxx" -MaxCharLength ([int]::MaxValue)
$Result | Export-Csv C:\Temp\MyProject\SUP_20160401.Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

You will get more than 4K text with MaxCharLength and be able to output it in CSV.

Comment: Why the intermediate `$Result` variable? Just pipe directly from `Invoke-Sqlcmd` to `Export-Csv`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content?view=powershell-6).

```powershell
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "xxxx" -Database "Vincent" -Query $SqlStatement `
    -Username "rminder" -Password "xxxx" |
  Set-Content -Path C:\Temp\MyProject\SUP_20160401.Csv
```